# Sending data to a web site over HTTP

Tags: c, http, authentication

i have a program that receives data from a wireless device over bluetooth...i now need to do some operations in the data and then send it to the website (web server!!!) as a .csv file...i also need to authenticate the device itself from it hardware address which is also obtained in the program.i am coding this in gcc linux compiler using C...can anyone tell me how do i go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the [LibCurl](http://curl.haxx.se/) library.  It handles uploading via HTTP and a number of other protocols.